# Editar archivo desde bash

Tags: bash

solicito ayuda, debo realizar una multiplicación de un numero dentro de un archivo, por un valor fijo, desde bash, el archivo tiene la siguiente forma, nuchas gracias. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alexander, te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido del nuevo usuario y revises Como Preguntar. Además recuerda que esta es una comunidad de ayuda, pero para que te ayudemos debés mostrar tu avance y que cosas has intentado.

Comment: Nery, Muchas gracias por tu comentario, claro que si realizare el reccorrido y eentonces reevaluare la forma de preguntar, y claro, mejorare en la estructura para que no luzca como solo solicitar copia. Gracias

Comment: Intenta poner texto en lugar de imágenes, así como qué intentaste. Sería bueno un [mcve] para tener más claro qué tienes y qué pretendes.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre algo así.

1. Obtenemos ese número que quieres y para eso utilizamos algún procesador de texto como cut, awk, etc. Entonces, usando el ejemplo que pusiste, sería algo así

   ```
   awk 'NR==1{print $2}' < tu_archivo  # Esto es suponiendo que quieres 
               # el campo número 2 y que sólo quieres el primer renglón.

   awk '{print $2}' < tu_archivo # En caso de que quieras todos los renglones
   ```
2. awk tiene una virtud la cual es que puede hacer operaciones, es un lenguaje, entonces podrías multiplicar esos campos por el valor que quieras.

   ```
   awk 'BEGIN{fijo=2}{print $2*fijo}' < tu_archivo  # En caso de que 
                    # quieras multiplicar los valores de todos los renglones.
   ```

Otra opción que se me ocurre (la cual no usaría una vez entendiendo un poco de awk), es con cut y tr.

```
valor_fijo=3; tr -s " " < tu_archivo | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs -I {} echo "{}*$valor_fijo" | bc
```

Lo que hace esta linea es, crear una variable llamada "valor_fijo", luego elimina los espacios repetidos con "tr -s", después, con cut, imprime el campo 2 separado por espacios y luego los imprime uno por uno con xargs añadiéndoles la cadena a multiplicar, es decir, quedaría de la forma "numero*valor_fijo" y eso se lo pasa a la calculadora bc.

Por supuesto que prefiero usar awk, pero es divertido mezclar cosas.

Respecto al último one liner, asumí que los campos están separados por espacios y no por tabs, por eso es que, tanto en tr como en cut, utilicé el " " como separador.

En todos los casos supuse que quieres los valores de la segunda columna, si quieres puedes cambiar esto modificando el número 2 por 1, etc.